# How to play with Control.Monad.Writer in haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm new to functional programming and recently learning at [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/), but when I went through [this chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more), I got stuck with the program below:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer  

logNumber :: Int -> Writer [String] Int  
logNumber x = Writer (x, ["Got number: " ++ show x])  

multWithLog :: Writer [String] Int  
multWithLog = do  
    a <- logNumber 3  
    b <- logNumber 5  
    return (a*b)
```

I saved these lines in a .hs file and but failed to import it into my ghci which complained:

```
more1.hs:4:15:
    Not in scope: data constructor `Writer'
    Perhaps you meant `WriterT' (imported from Control.Monad.Writer)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I examined the type by ":info" command:

```
Prelude Control.Monad.Writer> :info Writer
type Writer w = WriterT w Data.Functor.Identity.Identity
               -- Defined in `Control.Monad.Trans.Writer.Lazy'
```

From my point of view, this was supposed to be something like "newtype Writer w a ..."
so I'm confused about how to feed the data constructor and get a Writer.

I guess it might be a version-related problem and my ghci version is 7.4.1

Comment: For exercises, I recommend not importing the declaration and writing it on your own in the file.

Comment: I spoke to the author a while back, and he confirmed that the online version of the book is out of date. There's a more up-to-date version on PDF: [[here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/665999/learnyouahaskell.pdf)]

Comment: @Electric, I have the same question, could you please give a link? Your above link is broken.

Comment: @BulatM. [Here you go](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzCGYG05d-yGMUxzOWJwMGZDRXc)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

The package `Control.Monad.Writer` does not export the data constructor `Writer`. I guess this was different when LYAH was written.

### Using the MonadWriter typeclass in ghci

Instead, you create writers using the `writer` function. For example, in a ghci session I can do

```
ghci> import Control.Monad.Writer
ghci> let logNumber x = writer (x, ["Got number: " ++ show x])
```

Now `logNumber` is a function that creates writers. I can ask for its type:

```
ghci> :t logNumber
logNumber :: (Show a, MonadWriter [String] m) => a -> m a
```

Which tells me that the inferred type is not a function that returns a *particular* writer, but rather anything that implements the `MonadWriter` type class. I can now use it:

```
ghci> let multWithLog = do { a <- logNumber 3; b <- logNumber 5; return (a*b) }
    :: Writer [String] Int
```

(Input actually entered all on one line). Here I've specified the type of `multWithLog` to be `Writer [String] Int`. Now I can run it:

```
ghci> runWriter multWithLog
(15, ["Got number: 3","Got number: 5"])
```

And you see that we log all of the intermediate operations.

### Why is the code written like this?

Why bother to create the `MonadWriter` type class at all? The reason is to do with monad transformers. As you correctly realised, the simplest way to implement `Writer` is as a newtype wrapper on top of a pair:

```
newtype Writer w a = Writer { runWriter :: (a,w) }
```

You can declare a monad instance for this, and then write the function

```
tell :: Monoid w => w -> Writer w ()
```

which simply logs its input. Now suppose you want a monad that has logging capabilities, but also does something else - say it can read from an environment too. You'd implement this as

```
type RW r w a = ReaderT r (Writer w a)
```

Now because the writer is inside the `ReaderT` monad transformer, if you want to log output you can't use `tell w` (because that only operates with unwrapped writers) but you have to use `lift $ tell w`, which "lifts" the `tell` function through the `ReaderT` so that it can access the inner writer monad. If you wanted two layers transformers (say you wanted to add error handling as well) then you'd need to use `lift $ lift $ tell w`. This quickly gets unwieldy.

Instead, by defining a type class we can make any monad transformer wrapper around a writer into an instance of writer itself. For example,

```
instance (Monoid w, MonadWriter w m) => MonadWriter w (ReaderT r m)
```

that is, if `w` is a monoid, and `m` is a `MonadWriter w`, then `ReaderT r m` is also a `MonadWriter w`. This means that we can use the `tell` function directly on the transformed monad, without having to bother with explicitly lifting it through the monad transformer.

Comment: "I guess this was different when LYAH was written." Right. That changed with `mtl` going from major version 1.* to 2.*, shortly after LYAH and RWH were written. Extremely unfortunate timing that led and leads to much confusion among beginners.

Comment: I'm using GHC version 7.8.3 now and I had to import `Control.Monad.Trans.Writer`. In addition the type of `logNumber` is `logNumber :: (Show a, Monad m) => a -> WriterT [[Char]] m a` for me.

Comment: @kmikael You probably don't have the `mtl` library installed (which probably means you have a base installation of GHC, like minGHC, rather than the Haskell Platform). From a command prompt run `cabal update` and `cabal install mtl` and then try again.

Comment: Chris, I was using the Haskell Platform and the mtl was installed, I installed it again though and now it seems to work like in your answer. I don't know what was wrong. Thanks.

Comment: The printed copy of the book is correct instead. It includes a paragraph explaining that `writer` is used in place of `Writer` as the latter, the value ctor, is not exported by the module, whereas the former is, and it can be used to create the same value you would create with the ctor, but does not allow pattern matching.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor, today `FlexibleContexts` is needed for the `let logNumber x = writer (x, ["Got number: " ++ show x])` line to be valid.

Answer (score 9):

A function called "writer" is made available in lieu of a "Writer" constructor.  Change:

`logNumber x = Writer (x, ["Got number: " ++ show x])`

to:

`logNumber x = writer (x, ["Got number: " ++ show x])`

Comment: What does this add to the existing answers?

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar message from trying the LYAH ["For a few Monads More"](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more) using the online Haskell editor in [repl.it](https://repl.it)

I changed the import from:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer
```

to:

```
import qualified Control.Monad.Trans.Writer.Lazy as W
```

So my code now works looking like this (with inspiration from [Kwang's Haskell Blog](http://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-21-writer-monad.html)):

```
import Data.Monoid
import qualified Control.Monad.Trans.Writer.Lazy as W


output :: String -> W.Writer [String] ()
output x = W.tell [x]


gcd' :: Int -> Int -> W.Writer [String] Int  
gcd' a b  
    | b == 0 = do  
        output ("Finished with " ++ show a)
        return a  
    | otherwise = do  
        output (show a ++ " mod " ++ show b ++ " = " ++ show (a `mod` b))
        gcd' b (a `mod` b)

main :: IO()
main = mapM_ putStrLn $ snd $ W.runWriter (gcd' 8 3)
```

[Code is currently runable here](https://repl.it/@dowdeswells/MoreMonads)